# How to center align text in JTextArea?

Tags: swing, jtextarea, jtextpane, nimbus

I have requirement of Text wrapping + Text Centering + Nimbus Look and Feel + with a background color black. 
I tried out with the following 2 components 
**1. JTextPane** 
-------**supports: Text Wrapping + Text Centering using StyledDocument** 
-------**issue   : custom background color doesn't work Nimbus Look and Feel(be it disabled or enabled)**
which is bug as show here https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=ab1938d61a7fd83ca2b54eb8df7?bug_id=6789980

my jdk version is  : **1.6.0_33**

Fixes tried :

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TextPane.background", Color.RED);
```

but this also is unable to override the Nimbus default which is  **#d6d9df (214,217,223)** 
Can anyone help me with text Centering in the JTextArea?
Thanks in advance

**1. JTextArea** 
-------**supports: Text Wrapping + background coloring with Nimbus LnF (only when its enabled)** 
-------**issue : Text Centering is an issue in here**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213045/centering-text-in-a-jtextarea-or-jtextpane-horizontal-text-alignment might help

Comment: yes it works's but with JTextPane only and not with JTextArea.
I need to solve my problem with JTextArea only (because the background color cannot be set in the JTextPane with Nimbus LnF). Didn't had any luck with that as of for now , :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center text you should use a JTextPane not a JTextArea. Centering text is a big issue.

It is better to solve the background problem with the JTextPane.

When using the Nimbus LAF it looks like you need to provide a custom Painter to just paint the background as a solid color. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14256146/131872) by @mKorbel. You would need to change the property tag. Also in the FillPainter I changed:

```
g.setColor(color);
g.setColor(object.getBackground());
```

Comment: Thanks .... Working ,,,,
This is what I used ... 

         `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TextPane[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new FillPainter());`
<br><br>

`public class FillPainter implements Painter<JComponent> {
     @Override
     public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width,          int height) {
      g.setColor(object.getBackground());
     }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks .... Working ,,,,
This is what I used ...

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TextPane[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new FillPainter());`


public class FillPainter implements Painter<JComponent> {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width,int height) {
        g.setColor(object.getBackground());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to center text in JTextArea

```
public static void centerText (JTextArea ta)
{
    BufferedImage fake1 = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D fake2 = fake1.createGraphics();
    FontMetrics fm = fake2.getFontMetrics(ta.getFont());

    int lines = ta.getLineCount();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        {
            int start = ta.getLineStartOffset(i);
            int end = ta.getLineEndOffset(i);

            String line = ta.getText(start, end - start).replace("\n","");
            list.add (line.trim());
        }
    }
    catch (BadLocationException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    alignLines (list, fm, ta);
}

private static void alignLines (ArrayList<String> list, FontMetrics fm, JTextArea ta)
{
    String leading = "      ";
    int longest = -1;
    for (String s : list)
    {
        if (fm.stringWidth(s) > longest)
            longest = fm.stringWidth(s);
    }
    for (int n=0; n<list.size(); n++)
    {
        String s = list.get(n);
        if (fm.stringWidth(s) >= longest)
            continue;
        while (fm.stringWidth(s) < longest)
            s = ' '+s+' ';
        list.set(n, s);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : list)
    {
        sb.append(leading).append(s).append('\n');
    }
    ta.setText (sb.toString());
}
```

call CenterText with your filled JTextArea as argument